# Scala, JPA & nullable fields

Tags: scala, jpa

In trying to use Scala with JPA, I have the following snippet as part of the definition of an entity

```
 @Column(name = "ACC_INT", nullable = true)
 @BeanProperty var accInt: Double = _
```

All is fine until I retrieve some data and I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of com.jim.fi.sppa.RiskData.accInt; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of com.jim.fi.sppa.RiskData.accInt
    ....
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of com.jim.fi.sppa.RiskData.accInt
    at ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set double field com.jim.fi..sppa.RiskData.accInt to null value
```

I think I get what is going on here -- Scala is trying to treat my Double like a double, but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Comment: Have you tried declaring it as java.lang.Double?

Comment: That worked, and I suppose helps for java interop, but somehow leaves me disappointed.  Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Double` in Scala is actually `double`, the primitive type. For the wrapper type refer to `java.lang.Double`.